# Creating array2D doesn't work

Tags: arrays, f#, msdn, f#-interactive

Using [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) sample:

```
let my2DArray = array2D [ [ 1; 0]; [0; 1] ]
```

Trying to run it in F# Interactive, but get the following error:

> error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

I know I can use `Array2D.init`, but wondering why `array2D` doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you typed it correctly?  This is what I got: `> array2D [[1;0];[0;1]];;
val it : int [,] = [[1; 0] [0; 1]]`

Comment: yes, just copy and paste

Comment: just restarted VS and now it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single-line sample you posted in your question works fine for me, so the error is probably caused by some other code that is on the next line (or on the previous line).

For example, I get the error *"This value is not a function and cannot be applied"* when I write this:

```
let my2DArray = 
  array2D [ [ 1; 0]; [0; 1] ]
    printfn "hi"
```

In this case, the error is caused by incorrect indentation. The compiler thinks that you're treating the code on the second line (`array2D [ .. ]`) as a function and using the code on the third line as an argument (because it is indented further). Fixing the indentation (remove spaces before `printfn`) solves the problem.

It is hard to say what is the problem in your case, but I suspect something very similar.

Comment: yes, it works now, probably it was problem with VS